# How to Increase Number of Open Files Limit in Linux

Tags: kali-linux, ulimit

I'm trying to increase the number of files that can be opened by a user, but I keep getting the error:

```
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

Currently it's at:

```
rev@kali:~$ ulimit -n
1024
```

How can I increase the size, say to 999999?

Thank you all in advance.